# Solpart menu is ripping my soul apart!!! Not opening up in DNN

Tags: menu, dotnetnuke

Please, someone tell me if there is a replacement for the rubbish Solpart menu, the menu with the small arrow to administer a module in DotNetNuke?

I have been using DNN for some time now and I would love to know if there is not a better way to get this menu working. I cannot believe DNN would let something as buggy as that out!

Thanks

Comment: This is the actions menu I am talking about on each module ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any menu for that drop down. You'd just swap out the solpartmenu for the one you want in the container you create. Here is a blog post outlining some of the menu options available. I'd suggest taking a look into each one of these and see which would be a good fit for you.

[New Navigation Options in DotNetNuke 5.x Designers Should Know](http://www.r2idnn.com/Blog/BlogEntry/New_Navigation_Options_in_DotNetNuke_5_x_Designers_Should_Know.aspx)

Below is one (slightly updated) example from [How to use RadMenu instead of the default solpartactions menu](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet/menu/menu_howtouseradmenuforactionmenu.html)

1. Open an existing container for edit (a Default DNN container will work fine).
2. Register the `RADMENUACTIONS` tag by adding the following line of code: `<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" TagName="RADMENUACTIONS" Src="~/DesktopModules/RadMenu/RadMenuActions.ascx" %>`
3. Replace `<dnn:ACTIONS ... />` with `<dnn:RADMENUACTIONS ... />`
4. Set additional properties for RadMenu if desired. For example you can set the Skin property: `<dnn:RADMENUACTIONS runat="server" id="dnnRADMENUACTIONS" Skin="CssGreen" />`

Comment: Hi Ian! This is awesome and I have already been using RadMenu for some time already. I've read over that Blog entry but unfortunately, I still don't see anything that will replace that horrible actions menu.

Any more ideas? :)

Comment: I updated the post with an example for using Telerik's menu instead of Solpart for the DNN actions. Hope that helps!